# How are transactions broadcast from a personal Electrum server? Through the full Bitcoin Core node? Or by the Elecrum server itself?

Tags: transactions, broadcast, electrum-server

When wallet software is connected directly to `bitcoind`, you can see when the wallet connects to the node, broadcasts a transaction through the node, etc. by watching the `bitcoind` log. But when you connect your software wallet to the Electrum server (which is, in turn, connected to your Bitcoin Core node) no connection or transaction broadcast information appears in the `bitcoind` log. This makes me wonder: how are transactions broadcast when your wallet is connected to your personal Electrum server? Is it the case that it relays the transaction information to the Bitcoin Core node and then the Bitcoin Core node broadcasts the transaction to the network? Or is it that the Electrum server is, somehow, broadcasting the transaction itself?

To put the question another way: assuming that the Bitcoin Core and the Electrum server have different IP addresses, which IP is broadcasting the transaction?